# APA bibliography (apascite)

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

I'm new to latex and I've been having trouble citing with the apacite bibliography style. It just won't work and I have no idea why...

```
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage{algorithm2e,algorithmic}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Extra maths symbols
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{apacite}]]

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bib2}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone explain to me why it won't work? When I compile it there's an error on every \cite command
Thank you so much

Comment: Did you really try to compile the code above? It lacks both a `\documentclass` and a `\begin{document}` commands.

Comment: Your still-incomplete test document also lacks `\cite` instructions.